# Как лучше хранить контент в БД: HTML vs MarkDown?

Tags: html, mysql, база-данных, postgresql, markdown

Есть очень большая база данных с статьями.
Они сейчас в формате html.
Сейчас переходим на PostgreSQL, и возникла идея хранить текст в markdown.

Вопрос в том, будет ли от этого пользы?
Сейчас статьи занимают **~500GB**.
Если перенесём всё на markdown, они займут меньше места в БД?

При выдаче на сайте текста статьи, как конвертировать Markdown в HTML?
Этот процесс делается на сервере? Если да, то это большая нагрузка на сервер? (сайт довольно посещаемый)
Если на клиенте, то как на это будут реагировать поисковые системы?

Comment: Переход на markdown, конечно, снизит расход дисковой памяти для БД. Но именно что за счёт ресурсов веб-сервера, которому предстоит выполнять обратное преобразование. Да, учтите, что далеко не всё можно преобразовать в markdown (и потом развернуть обратно в HTML "как было").

Comment: То есть будет большая нагрузка на процессор, да?

Comment: Мне кажется что например StackOferflow или GitHub для комментариев, используют как раз хранение в markdown

Comment: Ну большая или нет - не скажу. Или пробуйте экспериментально, или поспрашивайте тех, у кого оно уже реализовано. Что же до SO/GH - я бы всё же не сравнивал статьи и комментарии.

Comment: А в чём разница? И там и там - текст

Comment: хтмл отрендеренный - его подругому не отрендеришь потом, а мд можно стилизовать по новой